# Poweredge R720 - Unrecoverable Medium Error on boot

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Poweredge R720 using a hardware RAID 5 array.

Earlier today the server experienced an unexpected power cut, and upon rebooting I was met with an "unrecoverable medium error" when the OS began to load:
[image]

The message will reprint every ten seconds or so, eventually giving up and dropping me into a recovery shell.

In system setup, I'm seeing that the RAID health is "optimal" and all physical disks are present and healthy without SMART errors.

The only reason I'm not convinced that this is necessarily a death sentence for the data in the array is that I'm not seeing the commonly-associated punctured stripe message, and when I have tried several times to boot into a live USB recovery environment with several different ISOs I am seeing the same error and am unable to boot into any OS that I have tried so far, including lubuntu, Ubuntu server, and Alpine.

Does anyone have any suggestions? My backups are not as recent as I'd like them to be so I want to exhaust every possible option before I burn the vdisk and start over.

Comment: run consistency check on raid with storcli /c0/v0 start cc https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/007.2203.0000.0000_Unified_StorCLI.zip  https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/12352476

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the fourth to last line, one of your disk had an unrecoverable read error. This means that the OS tried to read a sector which was unreadable (and probably accounted in the Current_Pending_Sector SMART attribute). The OS does not boot because a critical file is impacted.

To further diagnose the issue, please boot from a live usb and print the disks SMART data via `smartctl -a -d megaraid,0 /dev/sda`, replacing `0` (zero) with the incremental disk ID (ie: 0,1,2,3)

If stored data is not important and can be deleted, you can probably salvage the hardware (*not* the data it contains) by overwriting each disks to force the disk controller to remap the bad sector. Anyway, I would not use such salvaged disk in production setup.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, when I try to boot from a live USB I am still being stopped by the same errors. Do you have any tips on boot options etc. that I can use to bypass those attempts to mount the RAID array? This is occurring across several different Linux ISOs.

Comment: Disregard, I was able to boot into the live environment by letting it try and fail long enough to stop trying.